# Find all pages on Wikipedia that redirect to a specific page

Tags: wikipedia

On Wikipedia, is it possible to find all pages that redirect to a given page, like a "what redirects here" page instead of a "what links here" page? For example, I'd like to find all pages on Wikipedia that redirect to the page `[[Person]]`. I want to do this so that I can find redirect pages that should redirect to disambiguation pages, instead of redirecting to the `[[Person]]` page.

Comment: How do you want the results? Human-readable? Or machine-readable (e.g. XML)? Does it matter?

Comment: @svick I'd prefer human-readable results (i.e., results that I can actually read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the “What links here” feature to do that.

Either click on “What links here” in the Toolbox in the left menu and then click “Hide links”.

Or use URL like http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Person&hidelinks=1.

Answer (score 1):

AutoWikiBrowser has a "What Redirects Here" tool, as described in [the AWB manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBrowser/User_manual). You can use AutoWikiBrowser to find all redirect pages to a given page.